# Wired and Wireless connection missing

Tags: wifi, settings

After changing proxy for LAN to use manual proxy, I removed it only not to be able to connect to the internet via LAN or Wifi, I searched online for similar problem and solution, but after following http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2202508 everything about internet connection disappeared, now there is no way for me to connect to the internet, I need help please